# Google Map API Geocode Quota Uplift Not Honored

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I Have the need to be able to request 25,000 geocodes through Google map geocode api web service. I understand there is a 2,500 requests per day limit. Google allows the user to submit a request to uplift quota. I submitted a request and got an email with the following message:

"Your use of the Places API is initially limited to 1,000 requests per day. Please use this quota to evaluate and develop against the service. When you are ready to launch your App you can raise your quota to 100,000 requests per day by enabling Billing on your API project. To enable billing you must complete a credit card based identity check. Once completed your quota will be raised."

I followed the instruction above and still got only 2,500 requests per day limit. I was directed to post questions related to this matter on on stack overflow. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I did enable my billing, that what I meant by saying "I followed the instruction". the 1,000 requests is for Google places api, the 2,500 is for geocode api. I am sure I requested quota uplift for geocode api. Not sure why Google replied with places api. Maybe the 2 are very related.

Comment: same with me, infact it actually works for the Places API as they mention but not for the actual Geocode API which we require

Comment: Same here, did you find any solutions ?

Comment: I am in the same boat, guys :(

Comment: I am having the same problem.  They have my credit card info, ready for charging, but they won't increase the quota.

Comment: Similar question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780092/billing-issues-with-google-geocoding-api

Answer (score 0):

The geocode API and the places API are two different APIs.

Geocode has a limit of 2500 req per day, and can be increased by acquiring a "Google Maps API for Work" key. I think you need to reach out to Google for one of those.

Places API has a free limit of 1000 req per day. If you create a key on google developer console, and put your credit card in you will get your limit upped to 150000 req per day. Although 1000 is still the free limit.

Comment: Can you please see this question it's regarding geocodr class api limitation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144432/is-there-any-difference-between-android-geocoder-class-and-google-geocoder-api

Answer (score 0):

To access your uplift, you should 1) Get your api Key in google 2) Set it up in your string or code. Usually adding "&key=APIKEY" to the end of it.