# Billing issues with google geocoding api

Tags: google-api, google-geocoding-api

Billing was added to our gmaps-api project. And the billing definitely propagated, as it was added around 4 weeks ago.

In the project dashboard, billing shows as available. However, when we try to adjust our quotas, it says that we need to activate billing.

We contacted just about every channel at Google and were told that there is absolutely no provided support for billing issues with developer APIs.

Us: "We want to give you money."
Google: "No, and we won't help you."

Has anyone else encountered billing issues with API projects, and if so, how did you resolve them?

--- update ---

Note: Finally a rep reached out. You can ONLY get around the quota by getting a Google Maps for Work license.

The billing option is just a false lead if you're looking to go above the quota.

Comment: see my update to the original post

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  I can't seem to increase past 2,500 even though I've submitted all the billing.

Comment: So there are 2 limits.
1) You can only geocode 1000 addresses per day without billing.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems there are 2 limits.

1. You can only geocode 2500 addresses per day without billing.
2. You can geocode up to 100000 per day if you provide billing but you are limited to 2500 per session.

I seem to have this issue as well. I have a billing operation setup but I need to set up multiple sessions in order to go above the 2500 limit.

If you want to go above 2500 per session then you need the "Google Maps for Work" license. Is that correct?