# Is there any difference between Android Geocoder Class and Google Geocoder API?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-geocoder, geocoder

I want to launch my application, which is using Reverse Geocoding with the help of Geocoder Class but I want to ask whether this cause any problem further?

> - **Like do I have to add API KEY in my project?**
> - **Limitations in Geocoder Class (quota)?**

I have called reverse geocoding more than 4000 times (Using GPS Spoofing App) in an hour from the same device but its still giving me the result. Are there no limitations to use Geocoder class?

**What's the difference between Google Geocoding API vs Geocoder Class in Android?**

Comment: 1. Yes, you need to use an API key in order to use the Geocoder API.
2. The quota of the Geocoding API is unlimited. However,  If you exhausted the $200 credit, you won't be able to use the Geocoding API until it replenishes the following month.